# Incorrect syntax near '<'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Why is SSRS throwing an error stating that there is an incorrect syntax near my less than symbol?

```
-- ==========================================================
-- Create Stored Procedure Template for SQL Azure Database
-- ==========================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Campos,,Adrian>
-- Create date: <7/9/2014,,>
-- Description: <Query is meant to purge records in ONP_IL_MAYWOOD that are older than 3 months.,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE <Purge_Overnight_3Months, sysname, Purge_Overnight_3Months> 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
DELETE FROM tblOverNightPermissions WHERE DateAndTime < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE());
END
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Your query looks correct. Are you sure this is the one?

Comment: It's saying Line 6, is this line 6 in your query?

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer that's what is confusing me. Sorry I was not clear enough. Line 6 above is `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` yet it complains about the `<` character on line 23

Comment: Probably shouldn't be using `<` and `>` in your [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) statement.

Comment: I think this is the problem: `CREATE PROCEDURE <` Is that a procedure name? `Purge_Overnight_3Months, sysname, Purge_Overnight_3Months`?

Comment: Line 6 is 'AS', which is right after the `CREATE PROCEDURE` (ignoring comment lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `[]` to escape names in TSQL, not `<>`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Purge_Overnight_3Months, sysname, Purge_Overnight_3Months]
```

but you should not use such strange names anyway. How about

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Purge_Overnight_3Months
```

Comment: That did the trick! SSRS defaulted the procedure with this template that included the `<` thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `<Purge_Overnight_3Months, sysname, Purge_Overnight_3Months>` is a template parameter for Management Studio. While the file is opened in SSMS hit Ctrl-Shift-M (or choose "Specify Values for Template Parameters…" from the Query Menu). This should bring up a grid that says that there's parameter called Purge_Overnight_3Months (the first value in the angle brackets) with a datatype of sysname and a default value of "Purge_Overnight_3Months" (the third value in the angle brackets). Once you specify a value, and hit "ok", it will replace the entire angle brackets with the value that you chose.