# In PowerShell how to troubleshoot exception in DataSet.Fill?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using a function I found on SO to retrieve data from SQL server and generate XML.

```
function Invoke-SQL {
    param(
        [string] $sqlCommand = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
      )

    $connectionString = "Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$database;user id=$uid;password=$pwd"

    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
    $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
    $connection.Open()

    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

    $connection.Close()
    $tableOutput = $dataSet.Tables

    foreach($row in $tableOutput) {
        $xml  = $row | ConvertTo-Xml -NoTypeInformation -Depth 1
        $xml.InnerXML
    }
}
```

It works most of the time but, occasionally, exactly the same SELECT (except for the range) from the same database and table would throw the following exception:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near '>'."
At DBTest.ps1:22 char:18
+     $adapter.Fill <<<< ($dataSet) | Out-Null
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

How to debug what rows and/or what data gets the Fill method to break?

Comment: What is $sqlCommand at time of failure? I would check that first, typically this error is problem with the SQL command.

Comment: Yeah, that's a SQL error in your `$sqlCommand` e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39874629/478656 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661805/incorrect-syntax-near or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300057/incorrect-syntax-near or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086340/error-in-sql-query-incorrect-syntax-near - incorrect query, broken escaping, using features from a newer SQL server, etc.

Comment: Maybe your query is incorrectly written every so often. I would try putting a line like: `$sqlCommand>> c:\logs\myquery.log` immediately after your param(). Look at your query (or $sqlCommand) in that log file to see if you can catch it.

Comment: Where is the query that you are firing? Have you run the query directly in the ssms and checked if the query is returning proper data or not.

Comment: Thank you all, it was in fact occasional query being of wrong syntax. I wrongly assumed it was parsing of the returned data. I upvoted the first 3 comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, it was the SQL command itself. When you generate SQL commands make sure *every* variable goes through validation and sanity checks. As some comments suggested, *logging* queries can help with troubleshooting.